# Magento 2 Bug in validator.js file of module-payment?

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, bug

Found bug in **validator.js** file

Magento 2.1.1 path:`/vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/web/js/model/credit-card-validation/validator.js`

Magento 2.1.3 path:`/vendor/magento/module-payment/view/base/web/js/model/credit-card-validation/validator.js`

There is a validation in **Credit Card Expiry** for **Month** And **Year**
But Magento providing same validation for Month and Year.

For month: code starts from line no 61

```
'validate-card-date': [

        /**
         * Validate credit card number based on mod 10
         * @param {String} date - month
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        function (date) {
            return monthValidator(date).isValid;
        },
        $.mage.__('Incorrect credit card expiration month.')
    ],
```

For year: code starts from line no 87

```
'validate-card-year': [

        /**
         * Validate credit card number based on mod 10
         * @param {String} date - month
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        function (date) {
            return monthValidator(date).isValid;
        },
        $.mage.__('Incorrect credit card expiration year.')
    ]
```

There is need to replace 1 line of code : line no 95

```
function (date) {
            return expirationDateValidator(date).isValid;
        },
```

instead of :

```
function (date) {
            return monthValidator(date).isValid;
        },
```

How should I fix it?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think you should post this issue on Magento github. It should be `yearValidator(date).isValid`

Comment: posted on github and  It should be expirationDateValidator(date).isValid; because line no 23 (function ($, cvvValidator, creditCardNumberValidator, **expirationDateValidator**, monthValidator, creditCardData)

Comment: Look into dependencies, `expirationDateValidator` is `Magento_Payment/js/model/credit-card-validation/expiration-date-validator/expiration-year-validator`

Comment: @joni I am not getting you???

Comment: `expirationDateValidator` has incorrect name, actually, it's year validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created path and copy **validator.js** file:

```
/app/code/Nitesh/Module/view/base/web/js/model/validator.js
```

and made that 1 line change in that file.

```
return expirationDateValidator(date).isValid;
```

instead of :

```
return monthValidator(date).isValid;
```

Now providing correct validation for year.

Solved my issue.